# An efficient algorithm to calculate the integer square root (isqrt) of arbitrarily large integers

Tags: algorithm, erlang, biginteger, bigint, square-root

## Notice

For a solution in `Erlang` or `C / C++`, go to *Trial 4* below.

---

## Wikipedia Articles

[Integer square root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root)

- The definition of "integer square root" could be found here

[Methods of computing square roots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots)

- An algorithm that does **"bit magic"** could be found here

---

## [ Trial 1 : Using Library Function ]

### Code

```erlang
isqrt(N) when erlang:is_integer(N), N >= 0 ->
    erlang:trunc(math:sqrt(N)).
```

### Problem

This implementation uses the `sqrt()` function from the C library, so it does not work with arbitrarily large integers (Note that the returned result does not match the input. The correct answer should be `12345678901234567890`):

```
Erlang R16B03 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.10.4  (abort with ^G)
1> erlang:trunc(math:sqrt(12345678901234567890 * 12345678901234567890)).
12345678901234567168
2>
```

---

## [ Trial 2 : Using Bigint `+` Only ]

### Code

```erlang
isqrt2(N) when erlang:is_integer(N), N >= 0 ->
    isqrt2(N, 0, 3, 0).

isqrt2(N, I, _, Result) when I >= N ->
    Result;

isqrt2(N, I, Times, Result) ->
    isqrt2(N, I + Times, Times + 2, Result + 1).
```

### Description

This implementation is based on the following observation:

```py
isqrt(0) = 0   # <--- One 0
isqrt(1) = 1   # <-+
isqrt(2) = 1   #   |- Three 1's
isqrt(3) = 1   # <-+
isqrt(4) = 2   # <-+
isqrt(5) = 2   #   |
isqrt(6) = 2   #   |- Five 2's
isqrt(7) = 2   #   |
isqrt(8) = 2   # <-+
isqrt(9) = 3   # <-+
isqrt(10) = 3  #   |
isqrt(11) = 3  #   |
isqrt(12) = 3  #   |- Seven 3's
isqrt(13) = 3  #   |
isqrt(14) = 3  #   |
isqrt(15) = 3  # <-+
isqrt(16) = 4  # <--- Nine 4's
...
```

### Problem

This implementation involves **only** bigint additions so I expected it to run fast. However, when I fed it with `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111 * 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111`, it seems to run forever on my (very fast) machine.

---

## [ Trial 3 : Using Binary Search with Bigint `+1`, `-1` and `div 2` Only ]

### Code

#### Variant 1 (My original implementation)

```erlang
isqrt3(N) when erlang:is_integer(N), N >= 0 ->
    isqrt3(N, 1, N).

isqrt3(_N, Low, High) when High =:= Low + 1 ->
    Low;

isqrt3(N, Low, High) ->
    Mid = (Low + High) div 2,
    MidSqr = Mid * Mid,
    if
        %% This also catches N = 0 or 1
        MidSqr =:= N ->
            Mid;
        MidSqr < N ->
            isqrt3(N, Mid, High);
        MidSqr > N ->
            isqrt3(N, Low, Mid)
    end.
```

#### Variant 2 (modified above code so that the boundaries go with Mid+1 or Mid-1 instead, with reference to the [answer by Vikram Bhat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21658976/142239))

```erlang
isqrt3a(N) when erlang:is_integer(N), N >= 0 ->
    isqrt3a(N, 1, N).

isqrt3a(N, Low, High) when Low >= High ->
    HighSqr = High * High,
    if
        HighSqr > N ->
            High - 1;
        HighSqr =< N ->
            High
    end;

isqrt3a(N, Low, High) ->
    Mid = (Low + High) div 2,
    MidSqr = Mid * Mid,
    if
        %% This also catches N = 0 or 1
        MidSqr =:= N ->
            Mid;
        MidSqr < N ->
            isqrt3a(N, Mid + 1, High);
        MidSqr > N ->
            isqrt3a(N, Low, Mid - 1)
    end.
```

### Problem

Now it solves the 79-digit number (namely `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111 * 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111`) in lightening speed, the result is shown immediately. However, it takes 60 seconds (+- 2 seconds) on my machine to solve one million (1,000,000) 61-digit numbers (namely, from `1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` to `1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000`). I would like to do it even faster.

---

## [ Trial 4 : Using Newton's Method with Bigint `+` and `div` Only ]

### Code

```erlang
isqrt4(0) -> 0;

isqrt4(N) when erlang:is_integer(N), N >= 0 ->
    isqrt4(N, N).

isqrt4(N, Xk) ->
    Xk1 = (Xk + N div Xk) div 2,
    if
        Xk1 >= Xk ->
            Xk;
        Xk1 < Xk ->
            isqrt4(N, Xk1)
    end.
```

### Code in C / C++ (for your interest)

#### Recursive variant

```c
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t isqrt_impl(
    uint64_t const n,
    uint64_t const xk)
{
    uint64_t const xk1 = (xk + n / xk) / 2;
    return (xk1 >= xk) ? xk : isqrt_impl(n, xk1);
}

uint32_t isqrt(uint64_t const n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    if (n == 18446744073709551615ULL) return 4294967295U;
    return isqrt_impl(n, n);
}
```

#### Iterative variant

```c
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t isqrt_iterative(uint64_t const n)
{
    uint64_t xk = n;
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    if (n == 18446744073709551615ULL) return 4294967295U;
    do
    {
        uint64_t const xk1 = (xk + n / xk) / 2;
        if (xk1 >= xk)
        {
            return xk;
        }
        else
        {
            xk = xk1;
        }
    } while (1);
}
```

### Problem

The Erlang code solves one million (1,000,000) 61-digit numbers in 40 seconds (+- 1 second) on my machine, so this is faster than *Trial 3*. Can it go even faster?

---

## About My Machine

**Processor :** 3.4 GHz Intel Core i7

**Memory :** 32 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

**OS :** Mac OS X Version 10.9.1

---

## Related Questions

[Integer square root in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15390807/142239)

- The [answer by user448810](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15391420/142239) uses **"Newton's Method"**. I'm not sure whether doing the division using "integer division" is okay or not. I'll try this later as an update. [UPDATE (2015-01-11): It is okay to do so]
- The [answer by math](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17495624/142239) involves using a 3rd party Python package `gmpy`, which is not very favourable to me, since I'm primarily interested in solving it in Erlang with only builtin facilities.
- The [answer by DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15391357/142239) seems interesting. I don't really understand what is going on, but it seems that **"bit magic"** is involved there, and so it's not quite suitable for me too.

[Infinite Recursion in Meta Integer Square Root](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7795982/142239)

- This question is for C++, and the algorithm by AraK (the questioner) looks like it's from the same idea as *Trial 2* above.

Comment: `//` *is* integer division in Python, so Newton's method on `x^2 - n = 0` works.

Comment: @Blender : I know what `//` means in Python, and therefore I doubt whether it works, since the algorithm published in Wikipedia (and anything goes with **"Newton's method"**) works on real number (notice the footnote on floating point).

Comment: Using integer division doesn't make any difference. The sequence {x_n} is decreasing with a greatest lower bound of `isqrt(n)`.

Comment: @Blender : Applying the algorithm from Wikipedia directly and substituting division by integer division does not lead to correct results. Since Wikipedia's terminating condition is `abs(x[k+1] - x[k]) < 1` and since we're doing integer arithmetic, `x[k+1]` must be equal to `x[k]` in order to fulfil the condition. Therefore, when the algorithm applies to the input **3**: `x0 = 3`, `x1 = (3 + 3 div 3) div 2 = 2`, `x2 = (2 + 3 div 2) div 2 = 1`, `x3 = (1 + 3 div 1) div 2 = 2`, which causes an infinite loop. To correct this, terminate when `x[k+1] >= x[k]` (because of the reason you mentioned).

Comment: Ah, you're right. I was looking at the code in that first answer, which uses `x_{n_1} >= x_n` as the stopping condition. I think the Wikipedia example could be updated to account for both integer and floating point division.

Comment: Very nice solution!  I added some isqrt() benchmarks: 

 http://pastebin.com/vgg5JaKu

Comment: @Michaelangelo : Thanks for including my algorithm! As far as I can see, your algorithms target 64-bit unsigned integer, while my goal is on arbitrarily large integers (aka. big integers / bigints). I think even faster implementations exist for machine integers / fixed size integers - either by assembly or bit magic. Here is a good book on this: [Hacker's Delight (2nd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Hackers-Delight-Edition-Henry-Warren/dp/0321842685). [Here](http://www.hackersdelight.org/) is the official website of the book.

Comment: @AsukaKenji-SiuChingPong- np!  Yes, I'm ultimately looking for fast algorithms for my own bigint / arbitrary precision library.

I <3 Hacker's Delight! Great bit twiddling tricks

Answer (score 3):

How about binary search like following doesn't need floating divisions only integer multiplications (Slower than newtons method) :-

```
low = 1;

/* More efficient bound

high = pow(10,log10(target)/2+1);

*/


high = target


while(low<high) {

 mid = (low+high)/2;
 currsq = mid*mid;

 if(currsq==target) {
    return(mid);
 }

 if(currsq<target) {

      if((mid+1)*(mid+1)>target) {
             return(mid);
      }    
      low =  mid+1;
  }

 else {

     high = mid-1;
 }

}
```

This works for `O(logN)` iterations so should not run forever for even very large numbers

**Log10(target) Computation if needed :-**

```
acc = target

log10 = 0;

while(acc>0) {

  log10 = log10 + 1;
  acc = acc/10;
}
```

**Note :** `acc/10` is integer division

**Edit :-**

**Efficient bound :-** The sqrt(n) has about half the number of digits as n so you can pass `high = 10^(log10(N)/2+1)` && `low = 10^(log10(N)/2-1)` to get tighter bound and it should provide 2 times speed up.

**Evaluate bound:-**

```
bound = 1;
acc = N;
count = 0;
while(acc>0) {

 acc = acc/10;

 if(count%2==0) {

    bound = bound*10;
 }

 count++;

}

high = bound*10;
low = bound/10;
isqrt(N,low,high);
```

Comment: I implemented this before. I will check whether this or the Newton's method is better. The problem is that the multiplication is on big integer, not on a machine integer, so it is an expensive operation.

Comment: @AsukaKenji-SiuChingPong- integer multiplication takes about O(logN^2) hence this algorithm would O(logN^3) which still reasonably fast for your application.

Comment: Could you please explain the initial value of `high`? In your original answer, it was `target`, and you edited it 2 times to become `pow(10,log(target)/2+1)`. Why is it? Besides, since `target` is a big integer (bigger than `long long double` could hold), I'm afraid you need something like `ipow()` and `ilog()` to do the job (and that deserves another question), since the C <math.h> library cannot deal with it.

Comment: @AsukaKenji-SiuChingPong- You can surely use high = target but in this case you are needlessly calculating values which cannot ever be in sqrt range of target as sqrt(target) will be have half number of digits as the target so its more efficient to start with high = pow(10,log10(N)/2+1) which gives 2 times speed up over high = target

Comment: Okay, please let me make my question clear... I mean, how did you reach the initial value `high = pow(10,log10(N)/2+1)`? That means: when N = `10`, high = 10^(1.5) = `31`; when N = `100`, high = 10^(2) =  `100`; when N = `1000`, high = 10^(2.5) = `316`; when N = `10000`, high = 10^(3) = `1000`; etc. Why?

Comment: @AsukaKenji-SiuChingPong- all divisions are integer divisions hence for example target = 10^(2N) then high = 10^(N+1) and we know that sqrt(target) = 10^N hence by having this bound is tighter hence many multiplications are reduced.

Comment: @AsukaKenji-SiuChingPong- check my edit to improve the speed of algorithm

Comment: If you make the `acc = acc / 10;` into `acc /= 100;`, then `count` is not needed (and so do the `if (count % 2 == 0)`). Am I correct?